# Update sudo in Debian Wheezy for CVE-2021-3156

Tags: sudo

I have sudo 1.8.5p2-1+nmu3+deb7u1 installed in Debian Wheezy and I need to update it to fix the CVE-2021-3156 vulnerability. Unfortunately, there are no security patches for Wheezy anymore and upgrading to Stretch is not an option.

I can not install the sudo package from Stretch because it depends on libc6 (>= 2.17) and the version available in Wheezy is 2.13.

I have not found a patched sudo package for Wheezy. Do you know if it exists and where to find it?
Do I have to patch myself the source code? I downloaded the source code of sudo 1.8.5p2-1+nmu3+deb7u1 and checked the patches for sudo_1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u3 but the source code is quite different and I am not sure how to patch the code.

Comment: Wheezy (Debian 7) has been out of official security support for over 4 years now. Are you deploying manual fixes for all security issues? There are [hundreds](https://www.debian.org/security/2020/)... _"... upgrading to Stretch is not an option."_ Unless being vulnerable is an option, or you're getting significant time to spend on tracking and backporting security fixes (which will become increasingly difficult), I'd say upgrading to a newer release will become the only option.

Comment: I totally agree, but I need time to upgrade, that's why I said that upgrading wasn't an option. I needed to fix the sudo issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the simplest option for you is to build the Debian 9 version of `sudo`:

```sh
apt-get install devscripts libpam0g-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libselinux1-dev autoconf autotools-dev bison flex libaudit-dev
dget -u http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.19p1-2.1+deb9u3.ds
cd sudo-1.8.19p1
debian/rules binary
```

If the tests fail (they failed for me on `/dev/console`), disable them and build again:

```
sed -i '/build-simple check/d' debian/rules
debian/rules binary
```

You will end up with the packages in the parent directory, you can install those you need from there with `dpkg -i`.

Once all this is done, you can remove the build-dependencies:

```sh
apt-get purge devscripts libpam0g-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libselinux1-dev autoconf autotools-dev bison flex libaudit-dev
apt-get --purge autoremove
```

The same can be done using the latest sources from Debian unstable, [as suggested by Artem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631439/86440):

```sh
apt-get install devscripts libpam0g-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libselinux1-dev autoconf bison flex libaudit-dev zlib1g-dev
dget -u https://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/sudo/sudo_1.9.5p2-1.dsc
cd sudo-1.9.5p2/
debian/rules binary
```

(Traditionally, one would use `apt-get build-dep` and `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us`, but that won’t work here without making more changes to the package — it has some build-dependencies which can’t be satisfied in Wheezy, but the package builds fine without them.)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hand with this, I really appreciate it. It worked like a charm.

Comment: I upload a Docker file for build sudo following this steps for Debian 7 and 8. Also the .deb pacakges are in the same folder too. [https://github.com/rfrail3/misc/tree/master/CVE-2021-3156](https://github.com/rfrail3/misc/tree/master/CVE-2021-3156)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest simply building and installing the package from Debian Unstable:

Source files: https://packages.debian.org/source/unstable/sudo

Building a package: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html

The reason I'm offering the latest and greatest is because: a new package contains new handy features, e.g. the support for `/etc/sudo.d/` and probably other fixed vulnerabilities you're not yet aware of.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for pointing out this option. Eventually, I built the sudo package from Debian Unstable using @Stephen Kitt instructions.